# How to specify the target directory with mv?

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, file

I'm trying to move some files with GNU find on the command line, as in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154819):

```
gfind path_A -name '*AAA*' -exec mv -t path_B {} +
```

(added a 'g' prefix to find to use the Homebrew version of find.)

**Problem:** MacOS' version of mv doesn't have the -t switch and without it the command doesn't work. So, how can I move files with find on MacOS?

Comment: Did you read the second answere https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154828/5140 which has the comment "Works nicely on macOS (where the -t arg is not available on mv"

Comment: Also if you install GNU versions of find why not GNU versions of mv and other utilities. In Macports it is in the package coreutils I have no idea what it is in Homebrew

Comment: Actually, there is a coreutils package on Homebrew too. That gave me the GNU version of mv as gmv, which has the -t switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the GNU version of find you might as well use a GNU version of mv which will understand the -t argument.

Under Macports and Homebrew mv is part of the coreutils package and installing that will put gmv on your path.

Macports installation is by

```
sudo port install coreutils
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gfind path_A -name '*AAA*' -exec mv {} path_B/ \;
```

should work, you can even use `find` as long as you don‘t need any special functionality only `gfind` provides. You can also basically use any other answer in the Q&A you link to in the question :-)

Comment: Don't have `gfind` but that works with the default `find`. +1